# How to create customized component?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to create a data grid that has 4 columns: `description, quantity, price, and line total`. The line total will simply be the product of quantity & price. I want the last line of the grid to be the total of all line totals.

How can I create this type of grid? I thought of using item renderers, but I can't figure out how to have the last row be for the line items total.

If I must create a custom component, I'd appreciate book recommendations on custom component creation. While I have a general understanding of how to create custom components, I don't have a firm a grip on it as I'd like. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While you should definitely check out the links provided by www.Flextras.com, there are a couple of ways to provide the functionliaty you're after:

The simplest is a labelFunction:

```
<DataGrid dataProvider="{dp}">
     <columns>
         <DataGridColumn labelFunction="sumTotals" />
     </columns>
 </DataGrid>

 private function sumTotals(item:Object,column:DataGridColumn):String {
     return Number(item.quantity * item.price).toString();
 }
```

Alternatively, you could create your own itemRenderer, as follows:

```
  <!-- MyItemRenderer.mxml -->
 <mx:Label>
     <mx:Script>
         override public function set data(value:Object):void {
             super.data = value;
              this.label = Number(item.quantity * item.price).toString();
         }
     </mx:Script>
 </mx:Label>


 <!-- Your component -->
 <DataGrid dataProvider="{dp}">
     <columns>
         <DataGridColumn itemRenderer="MyItemRenderer"/>
     </columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; using either will certainly give me `line item totals`. However, as I understand it, I will not be able to use either method to display the `total of line item totals` in the last row of the data grid. If I'm mistaken, do let me know.

Comment: Oh, my apologies - I misunderstood.  Is using the AdvancedDataGrid an option?

Comment: Yes, using AdvancedDataGrid is an option; but how can I achieve the desired functionality with that?

Comment: In that case, check out the Grouping and Summary fields available in the AdvancedDataGrid - they should be able to provide what you're after:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bec.html

Answer (score 0):

A Flex DataGrid cannot include items that are not in the dataProvider, so adding a row that includes the total of all line items in the DataGrid is not practical, without extending the DataGrid.

Take a look at [this documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part4_CreateComps_1.html) for info about creating custom components.  Also take a look at this [screencast series](http://www.theflexshow.com/blog/index.cfm/Fifteen-Minutes-With-Flex). A direct link to [episode 1](http://www.theflexshow.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/3/2/The-Flex-Show--Creating-Flex-Components--Episode-1-Project-Setup).